# Order by within a partial render is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing a project in RoR, and I got to a point, I was wondering if I can do a partial render and then an order by, is a table, which I use in different ways, but contains the same data, Which would change the order of the data with the order by.
I want to do something like this:

```
    <%= render partial: "produto", order_by :preco%>
    <%= render partial: "produto", order_by :quantidade%>
```

This is the partial:

```
    <% @produtos.each do |produto| %>
          <tr>
             <td>
                <%= produto.nome %>
             </td>
             <td>
                <%= produto.descricao %>
             </td>
             <td>
                <%= produto.preco %>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <%= produto.quantidade %>
             </td>
             <td>
                <%= button_to "Remover", produto, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", 
                                          data:{confirm: "Tem certeza que deseja remover?"} %>
             </td>
           </tr>
     <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def index
        #@produtos_por_nome = Produto.order :nome
        #@produtos_por_preco = Produto.order :preco
        #com limite
        #@produtos_por_nome = Produto.order (:nome).limit 5
    end
    def new
        @produto = Produto.new
    end
    def create
        valores = params.require(:produto).permit :nome, :preco, :descricao, :quantidade
        @produto = Produto.new valores
        if @produto.save
            flash[:notice] = "Produto salvo com sucesso"
             redirect_to root_url
         else
            render :new
        end

    end
    def destroy
        id=params[:id]
        Produto.destroy id
        redirect_to root_url
    end
    def busca
        nome_a_buscar = "%#{params[:nome]}"
        @produtos = Produto.where "nome like ?", nome_a_buscar


    end
```

Comment: Without more context this is hard to answer. I don't understand how this is connected to the partial: Why not retrieve the products into `@produtos` in the `ProdutosController` and order them however you want them to order? The partial does not care about the order.

Comment: I use partial in index, where I want to make the order, and also use the partial in another page, that appears the products sought, without the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve..
In my partial, I removed the each became so ...

```
<tr>
                         <td>
                            <%= produto.nome %>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                            <%= produto.descricao %>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                            <%= produto.preco %>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                            <%= produto.quantidade %>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                         <%= button_to "Remover", produto, method: :delete,
                                                          class: "btn btn-danger",  
                                                          data:{confirm: 
                                                          "Tem certeza que deseja remover?"
                                                            } %>
                             </td>
</tr>
```

Where i call:

```
<thead>
      <tr>
              <th>Nome</th>
              <th>Descrição</th>
              <th>Preço</th>
              <th>Quantidade</th>
              <th>Remover</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <%= render partial: "produto",  collection: @produtos_por_preco%>

     </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
  <tr>
              <th>Nome</th>
              <th>Descrição</th>
              <th>Preço</th>
              <th>Quantidade</th>
              <th>Remover</th>
        </tr>
<tbody>

          <%= render partial: "produto",  collection: @produtos_por_quantidade%>    

    </tbody>
```

Controller:

```
def index

        @produtos_por_preco = Produto.order :preco
        @produtos_por_quantidade = Produto.order :quantidade
        #com limite
        #@produtos_por_nome = Produto.order (:nome).limit 5
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an argument to your partial

```
<%= render "produto", obj: @produtos.order(:preco)%>
<%= render "produto", obj: @produtos.order(:quantidade)%>
```

In your partial _produto.html.erb

```
<% obj.each do |produto| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: It did not work, it says `undefined local variable or method obj`

Comment: Change 'partial: "produto"' to "produto"

Comment: But it is the same thing "produto" and "produto".It does not change anything if I change, right?

Comment: I did this, I changed the 'partial: "produto"' to "produto" but not changed.

Comment: You have <%= render "produto", obj: @produtos.order(:preco)%> in show.html.erb and <% obj.each do |produto| %> in _produto.html.erb and you still get *undefined method obj*?

Comment: What version Rails are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try using below format:

```
<%= render partial: "produto", :locals => {:preco_data => @produtos_por_nome.order(:preco)} %>
```

In your produto partial template you can access like

```
<%= preco_data.each do |data| %>
    <tr>
             <td>
                <%= produto.nome %>
             </td>
             <td>
                <%= produto.descricao %>
             </td>
             <td>
                <%= produto.preco %>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <%= produto.quantidade %>
             </td>
             <td>
                <%= button_to "Remover", produto, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", 
                                          data:{confirm: "Tem certeza que deseja remover?"} %>
             </td>
           </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I can not do this, because I would have to change the partial every time, I use this same partial in `quantidade`, and searching, if I change to leave specific for `preco` would be the same as I put the table in the code. It is not?

Comment: Yeah if you make it specific for `preco` it would be same as the table you have coded.

Comment: Because it is but I do not want to, because I use the same table in three places, what changes, one will be ordered by price(preco), the other by quantity(quantidade), and another is normal.

Comment: Have you tried as @SteveTurczyn suggested, since it also reflects the same way i told in my previous comment with your requirement to use for all partials.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the option as a local variable.

```
<%= render partial: "produto", locals: {order_by: :preco} %>
<%= render partial: "produto", locals: {order_by: :quantidade }%>
```

And then use it in the partial.

```
<% @produtos.order(order_by).each do |produto| %>
```

If you absolutely can't change the partial, you can change the instance variable before you call the partial.  So the part of the code where you want ordre `preco` you would do...

```
<% @produtos = Produto.order(:nome) %>
<%= render partial: "produto" %>
```

You may want to combine the above into a helper method.

Comment: In two places I will use the order by, but there is a third party that does not use it. I would have to create another special partial for that location.

Comment: Ok, if you can't change the partial you can change the instance variable.  See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Ok, the error that appears is something like, undefined method 'each' for. 
`Showing /root/Alura/Projeto_camisas_exemplo/app/views/produtos/_produto.html.erb where line #1 raised:`
 `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`


`<% @produtos.each do |produto| %>`

Comment: Hi, ok, I misread your variable names.  Please try the edits I've made.

Comment: And one more change (based on your index method)

Comment: In this: And then use it in the partial.
`<% @produtos.order(order_by).each do |produto| %>`
it will work? Why do not you use the order by, and when I call the partial on that screen that does not use the order by, I'm going to need to give her an order, right?

Comment: Okay, I made the changes, but still keep giving the same error in each

Comment: Your error message `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` means you are not passing a @produtos collection to your partial. Check you are sending something from ProdutosController#index

Comment: Ok, yes, as pointed out by many people you don't have the instance variable created.  I've made one last edit to the answer `<% @produtos = Produto.order(:nome) %>` and that should work.  But you'll want to refactor this after you get it working.